# How to sort duplicate rows of values into unique rows and multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

Say I have a sample table like this:

[image]

And I want to make it like this:

[image]

Basically, it is making values in column A unique by moving all duplicate values of each unique row into the next column over. The important thing is that I can retain the order of the columns in the order that they appear in the row. For example, for the unique value '3', I need the next value for '3' which is '67' to appear in column 'C' and not any other column, because it appears 2nd in the list of rows.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9_jHZrmkHo) may help you. You need Microsoft's Power Query add-in which also comes as a built-in feature with Excel 2016 and 365.
For basics of Power Query please refer [here](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/power-query-basics/).